# VBSCipt LOGON Script - Evaluate two items and map shares accordingly

Tags: windows, vbscript, authentication

I have a logon script mapping user drives Windows Network. Some users are now logging into a terminal server these days and I'd like to map a different drive, based on computer name they are logging in to.

I am looking at which user AD group they are in (departmental group so I know which shares to map).

```
If IsAMemberOf(objNetwork.UserDomain, objNetwork.UserName, "Sales Dept. Users - Acton") Then MapIt "G:", "\\phillip\sales"
```

I need to now evaluate what the computer name is as well.

The basic logic is: If user is in *Sales* group from this computer *bur-ts-01*, then map this share *\\bur-fil-01\sales*; else, if user is in *Sales* group use *\\phillip\sales*.

It's a fairly comprehensive script mapping drives, printers, etc. Our VBScript person is long gone however and remote users are not able to access a local share to the TS server as a result.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or sample code that I could review?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check for the computer name to see if it includes "-ts-" and if so, then map accordingly.  A lot of different ways to write it, but here's my take.

```
bDomainGroupMember = IsAMemberOf(objNetwork.UserDomain, objNetwork.UserName, "Sales Dept. Users - Acton")
If bDomainGroupMember AND Not instr(objNetwork.ComputerName, "-ts-") > 0 Then       
    MapIt "G:", "\\phillip\sales"
ElseIf bDomainGroupMember AND instr(objNetwork.ComputerName, "-ts-") > 0 Then
    MapIt "G:", "\\bur-fil-01\sales"
End If
```

So basically, I pulled the function query out and assigned the value to bDomanGroupMember so you can use it in two checks without calling the function twice.  Then, the If / ElseIf checks to see if the user is both a member of the sales domain group and whether or not the user logged in from a terminal server session, ie. a machine with "-ts-" in the name.

Hope that helps :)